# Assembly Encryption Type 1 Font Encryption Algorithm

Tags: c, assembly, encryption

Im attempting to read in and Encrypt the contents of a file. Using the following code for the encryption function of which I transposed from C to assembly:

```
 unsigned short int r;
 unsigned short int c1 =52845;
 unsigned short int c2 = 22719:

unsigned char eencrypt(char plain) unsigned char plain;
   {    unsigned char cipher; 

     cipher = (plain ^ (r >> 8));  
     r = (cipher + r) * c1 + c2;    
 return cipher; 
 }
```

My code thus far is:

```
    .data
    file db "File.txt",0
    buffersize = 512
    buffer db ?
    filehandle dw ?
    cipher db ?
    r db ?
    c1 dw 52845 
    c2 dw 22719
    RSP db ? 


    .code
    org 100h

    start:

    mov ax,@DATA 
    mov ds, ax

    mov ah,3dh          ;open text file
    mov al,0
    mov dx, offset file
    int 21h
    mov filehandle,ax

    mov ah, 3fh         ;read file
    mov bx, filehandle
    mov cx, buffersize
    mov dx, offset buffer
    int 21h
    cmp ax,0


    mov dx, offset buffer 
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    call Encrypt

    Encrypt: 

           mov DWORD PTR [RSP - 4], 0
           movzx EAX, BYTE PTR [cipher]
           movzx ECX, WORD PTR [r]
           sar ECX, 8
           xor EAX, ECX
           mov DL, AL
           mov BYTE PTR [RSP - 5], DL
           movzx EAX, BYTE PTR [cipher]           ;# cipher
           movzx ECX, WORD PTR [r]
           add EAX, ECX
           movzx ECX, WORD PTR [c1]               ;#c1
           imul EAX, ECX
           movzx ECX, WORD PTR [c2]               ;#c2
           add EAX, ECX
           mov SI, AX
           mov WORD PTR [r], SI
           movzx EAX, BYTE PTR [RSP - 5] 

           mov ax, 4c00h
           int 21h

    end start
```

Im having trouble understanding how I would go about taking the text from the file sending it to the encrypt function and then printing the new encrypted code to the screen.

Comment: Write it in C, compile it then look at the assembly. Often the easiest way.

Comment: Please ensure you select the correct tags. C# is not C

Comment: In C the `r` is uninitialized for first call => random result => not possible to decrypt.

Comment: @Ped7g how would I go about initializing R with the contents of my file.